# How to add an object containing arrays to a class

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to implement something like this:

```
var settings = (function () {
    this.data = {
        array1: [],
        array2: [],
        array3: []
    };

    this.hasSettings = function () {
            //todo
    };
})();
```

What I'd like to do with it is:

```
settings.data.array1.push(item);
```

Unfortunately i get an:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'datas' of undefined

Could someone help me and explain the corrrect way to implement this?

Regards

Comment: this === the outer context. To use the function as a constructor you need to call it with `new myFun()`,. Instead you are calling it right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

white `console.log(this)` inside your IIFE... `this` is a `window` object. To make your code work change IIFE to immediately creating instance:

```
var settings = new function () {
    this.data = {
        array1: [],
        array2: [],
        array3: []
    };

    this.hasSettings = function () {
            //todo
    };
};
```

When you write `new function(){...}`, you immediately call a constructor function with `new` keyword. The `new` keyword creates a new object with properties of `this` and returns it (unless the constructor function returns a non-primitive value).

When you used [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), you just populated global object (`window` in browsers) with properties of `this`.